# If $V = \mathcal Z(xy-1)$ is the hyperbola $y=1/x$ in $\mathbb R^2$, how is $(xy-1)=\mathcal I (\mathcal Z(xy-1))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In Dummit & Foote (example on page $661$), it is stated that $\mathbb R[V] =\mathbb R[x,y]/ (xy-1)$. So, I'm assuming they are using the fact that $(xy-1)=\mathcal I (V)$ since by definition
$$\mathbb R[V]=\mathbb R[x,y]/\mathcal I (V).$$

However, I do not see why $(xy-1)=\mathcal I(V=Z(xy-1))$. How is this true?

Comment: How much do you know about the processes of taking $\mathcal{I}$ of a set and taking $\mathcal{Z}$ of an ideal? What have you tried to prove this statement so far? Knowing more about your background and your attempts on this problem will help responders tailor their responses to your current skill level and specific difficulties.

Comment: @KReiser I only know up to what is on that page in Dummit & Foote.

Comment: For those of us without the book in front of them, this is not particularly helpful. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Solution 1:

Let $P\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$.  We have 
$$P(t,\frac{1}{t}) = \frac{Q(t)}{t^m}$$
for some $Q\in \mathbb{R}[t]$ and $m\ge 0$. Now, if $P$ is zero on the real hyperbola then 
$$P(t,\frac{1}{t})= 0$$
for all $t\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, so $Q(t)= 0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. This implies $Q$ is the zero polynomial. This implies that $P(t, \frac{1}{t})= 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, so $P$ is zero on the complex hyperbola.  Now use the Nullstellensatz.

Note: In other cases, we could use analytic local parametrizations of varieties, as soon as the real locus contains nonsingular points.

Solution 2:

(only use basic algebra)

Consider $P\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. "Divide" $P$ by $(y x -1)$ with remainder. Since $y$ is not invertible in $\mathbb{R}[y]$ we will get an equality
$$y^n P(x,y) = (y x-1) Q(x) + R(y)$$

Assume now $P$ is zero on the real hyperbola. Then for all $y\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ we get
$R(t)= 0$, so $R$ is the zero polynomial. We get $y^n P(x,y) $ is divisible by $(x y -1)$. Since $y^n$ is relative prime to $(x y -1)$ we conclude $P(x,y)$ is divisible by $x y -1$.